# Can't remove a directory or `cd` into a directory that exist

Tags: command-line

I can not seem to `rm -r` or even `cd` into a directory that clearly exist but I get the error `No such file or directory`. What's going on? Relevant commands below. Should I force this or what? I would like to know why this is happening as well.

```
root@jaxsin:/var/www/camwright/core/components/databackup/dumps# ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Aug 30 11:19  modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Aug 30 11:20  modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377876001
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Aug 30 11:21  modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377876062
drwxr-xr-x 5 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 30 11:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 www-data www-data 4096 Aug 30 10:45 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   21 Aug 30 10:45 readme.txt

root@jaxsin:/var/www/camwright/core/components/databackup/dumps# cd modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941/
-su: cd: modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941/: No such file or directory

root@jaxsin:/var/www/camwright/core/components/databackup/dumps# rm -r modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941/
rm: cannot remove `modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941/': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Edit your question to show the output of `ls -Al modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941`. My guess is those directories are very shortlived.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `modx_camwright` directories' names appear to *start with a space.* If you look closely, you'll see that the letter `m` appears farther to the right on the line, than the names of the other entries. Furthermore, they are listed before entries that start with `.`, which is a clue that they do not start with any letter. (After all, `readme.txt` is "alphabetized" *after* the `.` and `..` directories.)

Or it could be some other weird character that `ls` shows as a space.

So, instead of calling the directory `modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941`, call it:

```
' modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941'
```

To `cd` to it, run:

```
cd ' modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941'
```

To remove it and all its contents, run:

```
rm -r ' modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941'
```

If those commands don't work, maybe the character at the beginning isn't a space. (It probably is--most other whitespace characters are shown as `?`s by `ls`.)

You can use `?` to match a single character. So, you can try calling this directory by the name:

```
?modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941
```

(Don't use quotes.)

Or if it's multiple characters, you can use `*`, which matches zero or more characters:

```
*modx_camwright_2013_08_30__1377875941
```

(Don't use quotes for that either.)

Most likely, just quoting the name and adding a space to the beginning (as described above) will work.

Comment: Nice catch Eliah!

Comment: Indeed a nice one!